# creating a registration profile in python django

Tags: python, django, registration

My goal is a Django application where upon registration, users are able to use the site, but that I prompt them later to verify their email (activate it). I send them an email verification email as they register, and then again if they can't find the email.

I'm using `Django 1.7.8` and `django-registration-redux`.

Here's my landing page view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login

from registration import signals
from registration.models import RegistrationManager

from drivers.forms import MyUserCreationForm

def create_registration_profile(user, request, **kwargs):
    user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    login(request, user)
    reg_manager = RegistrationManager()
    reg_profile = reg_manager.create_profile(user)
    reg_profile.save()
    print "Callback reached!"

signals.user_registered.connect(create_registration_profile)

def landing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            new_user.username = new_user.email  # my custom user has no username, just email
            signals.user_registered.send(sender='landing', user=new_user, request=request)
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp:dashboard"))
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = MyUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "landing.html", {
        'registration_form': form,
    })
```

Unfortunately, this fails on the creation of the `RegistrationProfile`:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.7.8
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration',
 'macros',
 'myapp',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
(u'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/me/Code/myapp/myapp_web/myapp_web_project/views.py" in landing
  29.             signals.user_registered.send(sender='landing', user=new_user, request=request)
File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  198.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/Users/me/Code/myapp/myapp_web/myapp_web_project/views.py" in create_registration_profile
  16.     reg_profile = reg_manager.create_profile(user)
File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/models.py" in create_profile
  115.                            activation_key=activation_key)
File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  370.         obj = self.model(**kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess it's because the user hasn't been created yet. You'll need to write some wrapper code to either create the User account if the user wants to log in, and then modify the activation code to expire or lock the user's account if they never click the activation link.